# Configure reinforced-typings to export class as AMD module

Tags: reinforced-typings

I'm using TypeScript and RequireJS in my project. RequireJS requires Typescript to export modules in a special way ([export =](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html) ) to model the traditional AMD workflow:

```js
class Foo {
...
}
export = Foo
```

Reinforced-typings project helps me to convert C# class to TypeScript module, and get output like

```js
module Module1 {
   export class Foo {
   ...
   }
}
```

I can't find in Reinforced-typings documentation how can I get `export = Module1`  directive at the end of the generated file.

Probably I should go for a custom `ClassCodeGenerator`, but I can't find how can I instruct it to *append* the resulted module with e.g. `RtRaw` code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In version 1.5.2 you can use visitor overriding for that:

```cs
using Reinforced.Typings.Visitors.TypeScript;
class AmdExportVisitor : TypeScriptExportVisitor
        {
            public AmdExportVisitor(TextWriter writer, ExportContext exportContext) : base(writer, exportContext)
            {
            }


            public override void VisitFile(ExportedFile file)
            {
                base.VisitFile(file);
                var ns = file.Namespaces.FirstOrDefault();
                if (ns != null)
                {
                    WriteLines($@"
export = {ns.Name};

");
                }
            }
        }
```

then

```cs
confBuilder.Global(a => a.UseVisitor<AmdExportVisitor>());
```

And you will get desired result.